# JavaScript timeout pop-ups on interactive page with AJAX background task

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout

My single page AJAX application does a recursive data gathering task in the background. The user can interact with the page while it's gathering data, and the database is potentially sizable. The user expects the gathering process to take some time, and they are OK with it.

To give you an idea of how the background scan works, here is the main recursive function:

```
// Recursive SVN directory scan
recurseDir: function (dirName, dirNode) {
  actC.setActive(1, "recurseDir " + dirName);

  // Load svnindex.xml using ajax, cache is optional

  // The path may contain hash or CGI information. Discard it.
  var myWiLo = window.location.href.split(/[#?]/)[0];

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: myWiLo + dirName,
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: ajaxCache,
    success: function (data) {
      $(data).each(function(){
        $(this).find('*').each(function() {
          // get XML entity name (we need 'file', and 'dir'),
          // and XML tag attribute "name" (we don't mind if it's undefined)
          var aTagName = $(this).prop("tagName");
          var anAttr = $(this).attr('name');

          // Make a new dynatree folder, recurse into directory, query the SVN server
          if (aTagName == "dir") {
            var newDirName = dirName + anAttr +"/";
            ctrl.recurseDir(newDirName,
                           dirNode.addChild( {   // ... and create new node
                             key: newDirName,
                             tooltip: newDirName, 
                             title: anAttr,
                             isFolder: true
                           })
                          );
          }
          else if ((aTagName == "file") /*&& /\.md$/.test(anAttr)*/) {
            ctrl.scanMdFile(dirName, anAttr, dirNode);

          }
        });
      });

      actC.setActive(0, "recurseDir.ajax " + dirName);
    } 
  });
},
```

"ctrl.scanMdFile()" extracts information from Markdown files (i.e. even more AJAX workload)

"actC" tracks the activity, and triggers some more processing once the recursive scan has finished:

```
  // activity counter object
  var actC = { 
    init: function () {
      this.actCnt = 0;        // pending AJAX activities during SVN scan 
      this.doneCnt = 0;       // completed AJAX activities  
      this.pBar = $("#progressbar");
    }, 
    active: function() {
      return (this.actCnt++) == this.doneCnt;
    },
    complete: function() {
      return this.actCnt == (++this.doneCnt);
    },
    progress: function() {
      return this.doneCnt/this.actCnt*100;
    },
    done: function() {
      return this.doneCnt >= this.actCnt;
    },
    setActive: function (act, who) {
       // keep track of deferred (AJAX) actions, indicate activity
      if (act == 1) { 
        if (this.active()) {
          this.pBar.progressbar({value: 0});
          ctrl.enterActive();
        }
        // console.log((this.actCnt-this.doneCnt) + " start :" + who);
      }
      else {
        if (this.complete()) {
          this.actCnt = 0;
          this.doneCnt = 0;
          ctrl.leaveActive();
          this.pBar.progressbar("destroy");
        }
       }

       if (!this.done()) {
         this.pBar.progressbar({value: this.progress()});
       }
     }
  }
```

"ctrl.leaveActive()" triggers the final processing.

Depending on the performance of the network connection, or of the server, FireFox 24 (LTS) on Windows XP or Win7 sometimes responds with a "script timeout" pop-up.

Is there a work around, or better, some Best Practice for data hogging JavaScript/AJAX applications?

Comment: It's rather big... but I gave extracting the core component a try ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer seems to be "use web-workers" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker).

According to http://caniuse.com/#search=worker we'd have to upgrade FireFox to at least release 26. The next ESR (or LTS) release will be FireFox 31, which won't be available anytime soon. Currently, using Chrome, or IE11 as the standard browser, is no option..

I'll also be looking into re-using data gathered during the last session.